# Forward slash used for active substitutions of pi-calculus

Tags: math-mode

I am wondering how i would typeset the parenthesized forward slashes seen below, including the positioning of the surrounding text?

[image]

To be honest, i have no idea whether this is a packet feature or whether this is built-in latex. I have skimmed through questions on forward slashes, but none seem to have considered the positioning of the surrounding text.

Comment: I don't know about the semantics, but `\nicefrac{a}{v}` inside math mode should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\zz[2]{\{^{#1}\mkern-3mu/\mkern-1mu_{#2}\}}

\begin{document}

\[V_B\zz{a}{v} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David. This comes pretty close. Is there an easy way to put a bit more space between text and slash? Otherwise it is great and exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @foobar just remove less space, I removed 3mu on the left and 1 on the right but change to whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\[
S[V_A\{\nicefrac{c}{v}\}^{chc}\mid V_B\{\nicefrac{a}{v}\}]^{\string\out(chc,\cdot)}...
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]